Blazor .NET 8 LINQ ViewModel Except
var users = await context.Users.ToListAsync();
var usersInLocation = await context.LocationsApplicationUsers
    .Include(lau => lau.ApplicationUser)
    .Where(lau => lau.LocationId == locationId)
    .Select(lau => lau.ApplicationUser)
    .ToListAsync();

return users
    .Except(usersInLocation)
    .Select(u => new UserViewModel(u.Id, u.FullName))
    .ToList();

Returns List that has count of 1.
But
 var users = await context.Users
    .Select(u => new UserViewModel(u.Id, u.FullName))
    .ToListAsync();
 var usersInLocation = await context.LocationsApplicationUsers
    .Include(lau => lau.ApplicationUser)
    .Where(lau => lau.LocationId == locationId)
    .Select(lau => new UserViewModel(lau.ApplicationUserId, lau.ApplicationUser.FullName))
    .ToListAsync();

 return users.Except(usersInLocation).ToList();

Returns List<UserViewModel> that has count of 3.
Trying to return the Users that are not in a Location as List<UserViewModel>
First code snippet returns List of count 1.
Last code snippet returns List of count 3.
Can anyone please explain?

Except without passing comparer uses Default comparer, which calls object’s Equals method. Analyze it.
